# How do I nest controls (components) in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

I made a little fancy checkbox called CheckBox2.
It works fine.
I made another component called CheckBox2WithNote.
When I InvokeAsync the bound values, I think I enter an infinte loop. Since I don't have InvokeAsync in CheckBox2WithNote the values don't get updated in the Index page.

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/9lhnrgtu

I'm obviously doing something wrong.
What is the correct way to nest components in blazor?

CheckBox2.razor

```
<label for="Yes">Yes</label>
<input name="Yes" type="checkbox" value="Yes" @bind="LeftOptionValue">
<label for="No">No</label>
<input name="No" type="checkbox" value="No" @bind="RightOptionValue">
@if(!Value.HasValue)
{
    <span style="color:red">Please Answer</span>
}
@code{
    private bool? _value = false;
    [Parameter]
    public bool? Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    public bool LeftOptionValue
    {
        get { return Value.HasValue && Value.Value; }
        set { if(value) { Value = true; } else { Value = null; } }
    }

    public bool RightOptionValue
    {
        get { return Value.HasValue && !Value.Value; }
        set { if(value) { Value = false; } else { Value = null; } }
    }
}
```

CheckBox2WithNote.razor

```
<CheckBox2 @bind-Value="MyValue" />
@if(MyValue.HasValue && !MyValue.Value){
    <label for="note">Why?</label>
    <input name="note" type="text" @bind="MyNote" />
}

@code{
    private bool? _MyValue;
    [Parameter]
    public bool? MyValue 
    {
        get { return _MyValue; } 
        set
        {
            _MyValue = value;
            //Can't do this here
            //MyValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);      
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool?> MyValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string _MyNote;
    [Parameter]
    public string MyNote 
    { 
        get { return _MyNote; } 
        set 
        {
            _MyNote = value;
            //Can't do this here
            //MyNoteChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> MyNoteChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
<div>
    CheckBox2
    <CheckBox2 @bind-Value="MyValue" />
</div>
<div>
    CheckBox2WithNote
    <CheckBox2WithNote @bind-MyValue="MyValue" @bind-MyNote="MyNote" />
</div>

<div>MyValue: @MyValue.ToString()</div>
<div>MyNote: @MyNote</div>

@code {

    public bool? MyValue { get; set; }

    public string MyNote { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should use radio button tags, and not checkbox. This is very confusing as you're using check boxes as if they are radio buttons

Comment: @enet That's the beauty of code, I can do whatever I want. Any idea what I'm doing wrong with my 2 way databinding?